# Typescript foreach loop has 'Expression has type `void`.' error

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up a cron job that looks for when my tournaments are done and runs some completion code.  I used this an example:

https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/

When I try to deploy my code, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: functions/src/index.ts:23:9 - Expression has type `void`. Put it on its own line as a statement.
```

Here is my taskRunner function:

```
export const taskRunner = functions.runWith( { memory: '2GB' })
    .pubsub
    .schedule('* * * * *').onRun(async context => {

        // Consistent timestamp
        const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();

        // Query all documents ready to perform
        const query = db.collection('tournaments').where('endDate', '<=', now).where('winnerUserId', '==', null); 
        const tournaments = await query.get();

        // Tasks to execute concurrently.
        const tasks: Promise<any>[] = [];

        // Loop over documents and push task.
        tournaments.forEach(snapshot => { // <-- error occurs on this line
            const { tournamentId, name } = snapshot.data();

            const task = completeTournament(tournamentId)
                .then(() => console.log("cron job", "Tournament '" + name + "' (id: " + tournamentId + ") completed successfully."));
                .catch((err) => console.log("cron job", "Tournament '" + name + "' (id: " + tournamentId + ") encountered an error: " + err));

            tasks.push(task);
        });

        // Execute all jobs concurrently
        return await Promise.all(tasks);

});
```

The completeTournament() function is defined further in the file:

```
function completeTournament(tournamentId: string) {
    // Get the top entry user id
    db.collection("tournaments").doc(tournamentId).get()
        .then(tournamentDoc => {
            const winnerUserId = tournamentDoc.get("rank[0].userId")

            db.collection("tournaments")
                .doc(tournamentId)
                .update({ "winnerUserId": winnerUserId })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error completing tournament '" + tournamentId, err);
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error retrieving tournament '" + tournamentId, err);
        });
}
```

I am new to Typescript so I may be doing the function pointer incorrectly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: On which line is that error occurring? If it's where I think it is then we need to see the contents of your `completeTournament` function. Either that or try explicitly stating the return type of said function.

Comment: Does `completeTournament` actually return anything?  Its signature suggests not.

Comment: I updated the line with the error above (sorry, I had it earlier and made an edit and forgot to add it back). I also added the `completeTournament` code.

Comment: I narrowed it down to the `.then().catch()` statements in `taskRunner`.  If I put a return statement on the first `db` call inside the `completeTournament` function and remove the `.then().catch()` calls in `taskRunner`, Firebase accepts the code.  Is there any way to structure the code to still be able to use the `.then().catch` in `taskRunner`?

Comment: You don't need to use then and catch at all.  If you're already able to use async/await, just keep doing that throughout your code.  It's awkward to use then/catch when you could use async/await instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer in the future:

You can see by the comments on my original post that I narrowed down the problem to the `.then().catch()` calls on `completeTournament()` in the `taskRunner`.  I ended up not using those calls there and instead relied on the `.then().catch()` in the actual work functions instead.